# Prec_replace - numeric before dot

Tags: php, sorting, preg-replace, rename

I'm just way to bad for this stuff. So I hope someone can help me here. =)

I need to sort some images with renaming and I want to replace a certain part of every image name in this folder.

Example name: 9600_2 [image]-0-0.png

I want to replace be dot and digit before png. In this case "0."  I don't have a f** clue how to tell preg, that I want the digit with a following dot, not the others... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\d+\./', 'REPLACEMENT', $filename);
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I mixed the slashes up in my head.. oh lord. Thanks allot and have a nice weekend. =)